# What sources of income do not require an SATR to be filed?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, self-assessment

For someone who is PAYE or unemployed, but has some income streams, when is an SATR required in the UK?

typical sources of income might include:

- bank interest
- dividends on shares you hold as an investment outside an ISA
- rental income from a property you own part/all of
- renting a room in your own residence
- freelance work within the personal income tax allowance

I know some of these (maybe all?) have tax free allowances, but is that the same as saying they do not have to be declared on an SATR if you are within those allowances?

So what levels of income in different areas could someone earn without having to do an SATR at all?

Based on the calculator supplied in the first answer, I discovered you can do quite a lot without needing a SATR:
[image]

It would be nice to improve on this, exactly how much you can earn from different sources before a SATR is required.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you need to submit a tax return if you have any untaxed sources of income.

HMRC has a handy [web page](https://www.gov.uk/self-assessment-tax-returns/who-must-send-a-tax-return) and even an online tool (linked from that page) which you can fill in to check:

> You must send a tax return if, in the last tax year (6 April to 5 April), you were:
>     - self-employed as a ‘sole trader’ and earned more than £1,000
>     - a partner in a business partnership
>
> You will not usually need to send a return if your only income is from your wages or 
>   pension. But you may need to send one if you have any other untaxed income, such as:
>     - money from renting out a property
>     - tips and commission
>     - income from savings, investments and dividends
>     - foreign income

Comment: I'm not sure that you can say "_typically_ you need to" inferred from "you _may_ need to send one if you have other untaxed income". I just tried that tool and was quite surprised at the results.

Comment: If you wanted to flesh out your answer with thresholds and so on, this is a neat one: https://www.gov.uk/rent-room-in-your-home/the-rent-a-room-scheme